# Not getting touch events in Google Chrome Windows 10 after Multi-Touch or Gesture

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, windows-10

We are building a kiosk app and noticing some odd behavior with Google Chrome. To debug, we are monitoring all of the incoming events with `monitorEvents(document);` through the dev console and noticed 2 different kind of scenarios.

1. Eventually after a few minutes of heavy multi-finger/gesture use, we are stuck in a touchstart/touchend loop where touchend does not propagate down to a mouse/click event (breaking our app as we only handle onClick). It is continuously stuck in touchstart-touchend-touchstart-touchend for every finger click.
2. A continuation of scenario 1 with heavier use, we are getting absolutely no events in the console, not even a touchstart.

We are using Chrome 62 with Windows 10 with the following flags:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --kiosk --incognito --disable-pinch --overscroll-history-navigation=0 URL

We have tried to add --touch-events, add --disable-gpu, remove our previous flags, but still facing the same issue. It seems to be an issue between Chrome and Windows as we are able to replicate it on google.com (with getting no events). When we plug in a mouse, we are able to click the buttons so the app is not frozen, we are just not getting any touch events (only mouse works at this point). Touch is still working on the Windows and Chrome App level, just not our app viewport.

The kiosk is a Dell All-in-One machine. Has anyone else experienced this kind of issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try disabling the addons or extensions? We had similar problem and a fresh install fixed it. I am not sure if that will help you though!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we had a few default ones like Google Sheets, etc. and we completely removed them. Unfortunately, we are still able to reproduce the issue. Its looking more and more like a chrome bug to me though as the issue is only inside the viewport/document level.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:  Using Chrome 68+ I no longer have this issue.  I have not tried versions between 62 and 68 to see where it was fixed but I am glad that it is!

It is a little late now, but maybe this will bring some closure.  I experienced the same problem and like you, only in Chrome.  The best I could determine was that this glitch is dependent on a particular model of touchscreen in the computer.

Check the hardware IDs for the touchscreen in Device Manager.  Only the Inspiron 20-3059 models with a touchscreen made by Advanced Silicon (VID_2149&PID_4C39) exhibit this behavior.  Other 20-3059 models with a different touchscreen model (VID_0457&PID_1192) work fine.

Oddly enough, later Inspiron 20-3064 models also work fine, though they also had Advanced Silicon touchscreens.  The PID was increased to 4C3E so perhaps they discovered this issue and fixed it for the newer model.

I wasn't able to find any combination of driver/firmware/Chrome versions that would fix the problem, but this is as close to a root cause as I could get.